# Why are the elements not inside of the body when their positions are absolute/fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I set the `body` position to `relative`, then I'm trying to position `#first` and `#second` elements relative to their parents, i.e. the `body`.

My question is why the `#first` element is not inside of the `body` when their positions are absolute/fixed?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#first {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 200px;
  border: solid green;
}

#second {
  border: solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="first"></section>
  <section id="second"> </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: they both are, your `#first` div just doesn't have a height and width set.

Comment: Fixed position does not obey the parent.  It simply stays in one place as the page scrolls.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nuz5k3op/9/ - - They are...

Comment: Please add `html,body{ min-height:100vh}`

Comment: When using `position: fixed`, the element is positioned relative to the viewport, not to any other element, so your code works as it is suppose to.

Answer (score -1):

I think I see what the issue is.  The above comment is correct in that it is easier to see the elements if you add a height and width.

Another thing to consider is the z-index context that is created when you set element positions.

Without setting the z-index, the first element is inside the body, but is behind the second element.  Check out the link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/rollinglex/s1Ltf93n/2/

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
  }

          #first {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            background-color: green;
            z-index: 100;
          }

          #second {
            background-color: blue;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            height: 200px;
            padding: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
          }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question has nothing to do with `z-index`, it just works as it is suppose to, so this answer doesn't add or help in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I had posted the wrong jsfiddle link.
In the question, the asker is wondering why the first element is not inside the body element.  Obviously, it is.  But when the first element is given height and width, it is hidden behind the second element. That may be why the element is not being seen by the asker.  So increasing the z-index value of the first element will clearly show that it is in the body.  Checkout  the fiddle I updated and remove the z-index of the first element to see it disappear.